# Access a Viewbag like an Array?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewbag

Imagine a view bag called

```
 ViewBag.Modes
```

this contains the following:

```
Simple
Advanced
Manual
Complete
```

How can I access the viewbag by index like you would in an array?

e.g Simple  is at index 0 then it would look like this

```
ViewBag.Modes[0]
```

I tried the above but it doesn't work so...How can I replicate this with viewbag or is there a workaround I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the posts but shortly after writing this I came up with this solution using a model & list as below this could also be done using viewbag instead of model.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
            foreach (Models.AppModeInfo blah in Model.theAppModes)
            {
                list.Add(blah.Name);
            }

            var AppModeText = "";
            switch (item.AppModeId)
            {
                case 1:
                    AppModeText = list[0];
                    break;
                case 2:
                    AppModeText = list[1];
                    break;
                case 3:
                    AppModeText = list[2];
                    break;
                case 4:
                    AppModeText = list[3];
                    break;
                case 5:
                    AppModeText = list[4];
                    break;
            }
```

Answer (score 8):

This does the trick for me:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var stringArray = new string[3] { "Manual", "Semi", "Auto"};
    ViewBag.Collection = stringArray;
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
    @foreach(var str in ViewBag.Collection)
    {
        @Html.Raw(str); <br/>
    }

    @for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++ )
    {
        @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Collection[i]) <br/>
    }
```

Output:

[image]

Sorry for not using your terms. I was scrachting this together from the top of my head.

Answer (score 4):

ViewBag is a dynamic property, which complicates things a bit.

For the behavior you're looking for, you might want to use ViewData instead. ViewData is a dictionary, which means you can access the values of each index using Linq:

```
this.ViewData.Keys.ElementAt(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your controller:

```
string[] Modes = {"Simple", "Advanced", "Manual", "Complete" };
ViewData["Modes"] = Modes;
```

In your View:

```
<div>
    @(((string[])ViewData["Modes"])[0]) 
</div>
<div>
    @(((string[])ViewData["Modes"])[1]) 
</div>
<div>
    @(((string[])ViewData["Modes"])[2]) 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Using the ViewBag:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
List<string> modes = new List<string>();
modes.Add("Simple");
modes.Add("Advanced");
modes.Add("Manual");
modes.Add("Complete");
ViewBag["Modes"] = modes;
return View();
}
```

**View**

```
<h1>List of Modes</h1>
@{foreach (var mode in ViewBag.Modes) {
    <li>
        @hobby
    </li>
} }
```

### ----------------------------------------------------------------

## Using the ViewData:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string[] Modes = {"Simple", "Advanced", "Manual", "Complete" };
    ViewData["Modes"] = Modes;
    return View();
}
```

**View

```
<h1>List of Modes</h1>
@foreach (string mode in ViewData["Modes"] as string[]) {
    <li>
        @mode
    </li>
}
```