# Trying to pass string of data from controller to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i am trying to pass string of data from controller to view using viewbag
but not able to fetch the value

in view side i have received the string of array values in viewbag
at controller side and want to fill column of table in view side

controller

```
 object o = command.Parameters["var_value"].Value;
 if (o != null)
 {
  string val = o.ToString();
  string[] values = val.Split('~');
  ViewBag.values = values;
}
```

View

```
var values=@ViewBag.values as string[];
<table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
         </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>values[1]</td>
            <td>values[2]</td>
            <td>values[3]</td>
         </tr>
```

Expected:Values should be bind in column at view side
Actual:values are not bind in column at view side

Comment: Hi Mohan, can you paste the exact code in your view? I see a few mistakes, one of which is you didn't include @ symbol for the razor engine to understand it as a server side variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the variable in a C# code block.

```
@{
    var values = ViewBag.values as string[];
}

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
     </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@values[0]</td>
        <td>@values[1]</td>
        <td>@values[2]</td>
     </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

use it like this::

```
@foreach(var str in ViewBag.Collection)
{
    @Html.Raw(str); <br/>
}

@for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++ )
{
    @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Collection[i]) <br/>
}
```

check out this link:
[Access a Viewbag like an Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26018361/access-a-viewbag-like-an-array)